# Are equivalences of categories étale?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $f:\cal{X}\rightarrow\cal{Y}$ be a morphism of categories fibred in groupoids over $(Sch/S)_{fppf}$. Assume that $f$ is an equivalence and is representable by algebraic spaces. Then is $f$ étale?

Here is my attempt. Let $U$ be a scheme. Then we have an equivalence $(Sch/U)_{fppf}\times_{\cal{Y}}{\cal{X}}\rightarrow (Sch/U)_{fppf}$. However, it seems that this can not give rise to an isomorphism $U\rightarrow U$. Hence, I think that $f$ is not étale.

More concretely, if $g:U\rightarrow V$ is a morphism of schemes which has a morphism $h:V\rightarrow U$ such that $gh\simeq1,hg\simeq1$, then is $g$ étale?

Here is the definition of properties of morphisms representable by algebraic spaces in Stack Project.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the question you are asking is. A morphism is algebraic stacks if it is locally etale on the target -- an equivalence is clearly locally an isomorphism on the target so obviously etale. Are you instead asking why a morphism of schemes, viewed as a morphism of stacks, is etale if you assume the morphism of stacks is an equivalence? It is in fact an isomorphism in this case, so trivially etale. Maybe something that will help you sort through the confusion: what does $gh\simeq 1$ even mean?

Comment: @Alex Youcis: I mean if $\cal{S}_{f}$ is an equivalence, then is $f$ an isomorphism? $\cal{S}$ is the functor induced by split categories fibred in groupoids.

Comment: Yes, it is what you just said.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page -- are you asking why an equivalence between discrete groupoids (i.e. sets) is a bijection, or are you not sure why what i just said is equivalent to your question?

Comment: @Alex Youcis: Yes, I'm asking what you have said.

Comment: Ah, OK. So I think this may just sound more complicated than it really is. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are sets, thought of as discrete categories (i.e. the only arrows are identity arrows) and we have functors $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g\cong \mathrm{id}$ and $g\circ f\cong \mathrm{id}$. Well, what does it mean for $f\circ g\cong \mathrm{id}$? It menas that fro all $y\in Y$ we have, in particular, an isomorphism $f(g(y))\to y$. But, as the only arrows in $Y$ are identity, this implies that $f(g(y))=y$. Since that held true for all $y$ you see that in fact

Comment: that $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}$, and similarly you can show that $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}$ so in fact $f$ and $g$ are set-theoretic inverses, so $f$ (and $g$) is a bijection.

Comment: @Alex Youcis: I get it! Thanks.